# Android NDk and CLI

Tags: android, c, command-line-interface, android-ndk

Is it possible to use CLI - Command Line Interface in Android NDK?? Is there such a function: exec (query)?
Ie is it possible to make queries from the command line C program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**officially**

i have never seen commandline programs on android, whether written in java or android ndk.

**unofficially**
i have seen commandline c/c++ programs targeting arm processors and the authors claimed they run on android eg [follow this link to whet your appetite](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dffafba924e3a2e6/185fa4fdcc99bd8e)

**My thoughts**?
Should you write such 'unofficial' applications, i doubt that you will be able to distribute them to your customers eg through the **android market** since android applications are dalvik executables(kind of java applications compiled and optimised for the dalvik virtual machine)